# R plotting: rectangle outside the frame when saving as SVG

Tags: r, svg, plot

I am plotting a rectangle and saving it as a svg.
The code works fine but I realized the rectangle gets slightly
out of the frame (see image top right corner).

This is the code I have so far:

```
svg(filename='/path/to/save/test.svg',width=2, height=3)
plot(1,1,col=0,xlim=c(1,30),ylim=c(0.85,1),ylab='',main='test')
rect(0,0.75,85,1,col=2)
dev.off()
```

Saving it as pdf solves the issue but I would prefer a svg solution. [image: Example of saved image]

Comment: Looks fine when I opened using GoogleChrome, I can still see the white long rectangle on the top, and I can see the black line on the right.

Comment: Are you trying to colour the plotting area - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16643736/680068

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the rectangle, its the axis. Set the axis origin to be plotted to 0 using `xaxs` and `yaxs` :

```
svg(filename='test.svg',width=2, height=3)
plot(1,1,col=0,xlim=c(1,30),ylim=c(0.85,1),ylab='',main='test', xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
rect(0,0.75,85,1,col=2)
dev.off()
```

[image]